# Getting the prototype of an object as a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, reflection, prototype

So I have a situation where I am trying out some DI based approached in JS, now lets not discuss the worth or validity of DI in JS etc let us just focus on the question.

So I get a targetConstructor, which would be something like:

```
function SomeClass(){};
doSomethingWithTargetConstructor(SomeClass);
```

So the above would pass the constructor of `SomeClass` into the method and that all works fine, however there is a test case which I cannot find a way to solve, as the targetConstructor will be a named function so you can extract the name from it. However the below situation does not work:

```
var someRootNamespace = {};
someRootNamespace.someSubNamespace = {};
someRootNamespace.someSubNamespace.someNamespacedClass = function(someArg){};
doSomethingWithTargetConstructor(someRootNamespace.someSubNamespace.someNamespacedClass);
```

So in the above example you cannot extract the name of the target constructor as it is a nameless function, HOWEVER in the debugger (as seen below) you can see that the targetConstructor prototype does contain the name information needed.

[image: Example of debugger showing the info I need]

As basically I want the string representation of `someRootNamespace.someSubNamespace.someNamespacedClass`

However I cannot for the life of me find a way to get at the information shown in the debugger, so is it even possible to get at? and if so how do you go about it? as the information is there, I just need a way to get access to it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible... Consider this: `var fn = someRootNamespace.someSubNamespace.someNamespacedClass; doSomethingWithTargetConstructor(fn);` Now, should you get `fn` or `someRootNamespace.someSubNamespace.someNamespacedClass`? And the debugger has more access to the internals than what's exposed through JS.

Comment: Yeah, which is a shame but as it is a proof of concept I just wanted to know if it would work. As currently I use a dictionary based approach to dependency management and wanted to see how hard it would be to actually do something based upon constructor injection and EVERYTHING was looking great until I get to the test cases with namespaced objects :(